# android build.gradle module app error : Failed to resolve: annotation

Tags: android, gradle

gradle comes up with one error message :

> Failed to resolve: annotation

**UPDATE** :

app gradle module :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

 android {
     compileSdkVersion 28
     buildToolsVersion "28.0.1"
     defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.isatelco.dietuser"
         minSdkVersion 16
         targetSdkVersion 28
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
         testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }
     buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
    } }

 dependencies{
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3'
     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3' }
```

and my project module :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha03'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

the app module is where error points.thk

Comment: can you add your full gradle and logcat error please? and explain when it happends and what are you trying to do ?

Comment: there is nothing but just this error @GastónSaillén

Comment: can you please paste your gradle module app and project one ? because its like seeing an error blinded

Comment: @GastónSaillén i update my question

Comment: ok, now i can see its kotlin and not java, its good to fill your questions with information in order to get help fast :)

Comment: @GastónSaillén ok iam sorry but gradle is gradle ;)

Comment: can you give me the full logcat stacktrace to see more clearly the error ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your build tools and sdk tools are up to date , to check them and update them if necesary just do this

[image]

[image]

rebuild gradle and tell me if that helped